# Font with PSTricks and Beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, pstricks, postscript

I am creating standard beamer presentations. Moreover I use PSTricks to produce my pictures in a separate file. Afterwards I include the pdf with the pictures into the presentation.

Unfortunatelly the font of the beamer package and the font of the PSTricks package is different. I am not an expert in "font stuff" but the PSTricks output seems to have serifs.

How can I streamline it? I couldn't find any adjustment in PSTricks to get exactly the same font as it is in Beamer. I would like to keep the font of beamer and adjust the font of PSTricks.

Thanks a lot!

***Adding a Minimal Example:***

@Henri Menke: I recognized that your suggestion works for text, but not for mathematical code.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,a4paper,oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage[american,ngerman,german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pstricks, pstricks-add, pst-3dplot, pst-3d, pst-plot, pst-fill, pst-node, pst-eucl}
\newcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
   \centering
   \begin{pspicture}[showgrid = false](0,0)(4,4)
    \rput(2,2){Hello $x$}
   \end{pspicture}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like that:

[image]

How can I fix it for mathematical code as well?

Comment: In the document which you use to create the PSTricks figure, place `\sffamily` after `\begin{document}` or add `\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}` to the preamble.  If this does not solve your problem please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## sansmath

It is easy to achieve sans serif math with the `sansmath` package.  For `sansmath` to be able to pick up the correct font it has to be loaded *after* the sans serif font (here package `helvet`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{sansmath} % load sansmath after the font
\begin{document}
\sffamily\sansmath
$g$ in math mode

g in text mode
\end{document}
```

[image]

## beamer

The `beamer` documentclass does not use the `sansmath` package, but perform substitutions on its own.  These rules are defined in `beamerbasefont.sty`.  To use them in own documents one has to strip out some internal macros and copy them to the preamble.  Also here, the sans serif font has to be loaded *prior* to applying the substitutions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
% from beamerbasefont.sty
\def\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\def\mathfamilydefault{\sfdefault}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{normal}{OT1}{cmss}{\mddefault}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{cmss}{\bfdefault}{n}

\DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{\encodingdefault}{\mathfamilydefault}{\mddefault}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{pureletters}{\encodingdefault}{\mathfamilydefault}{\mddefault}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{normal}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{\mddefault}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{\encodingdefault}{\mathfamilydefault}{\bfdefault}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{\mddefault}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit}{\encodingdefault}{\mathfamilydefault}{\mddefault}{it}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{\encodingdefault}{\ttdefault}{\mddefault}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{numbers}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{\mathfamilydefault}{\bfdefault}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{pureletters}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{\mathfamilydefault}{\bfdefault}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{\bfdefault}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{\mathfamilydefault}{\bfdefault}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{\bfdefault}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{\mathfamilydefault}{\bfdefault}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{\ttdefault}{\bfdefault}{n}

\makeatletter
\def\operator@font{\mathgroup\symnumbers}
\makeatother

\DeclareMathSymbol{0}\mathalpha{numbers}{"30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}\mathalpha{numbers}{"31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}\mathalpha{numbers}{"32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}\mathalpha{numbers}{"33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}\mathalpha{numbers}{"34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}\mathalpha{numbers}{"35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}\mathalpha{numbers}{"36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}\mathalpha{numbers}{"37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}\mathalpha{numbers}{"38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}\mathalpha{numbers}{"39}

\DeclareMathSymbol{A}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"41}
\DeclareMathSymbol{B}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"42}
\DeclareMathSymbol{C}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"43}
\DeclareMathSymbol{D}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"44}
\DeclareMathSymbol{E}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"45}
\DeclareMathSymbol{F}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"46}
\DeclareMathSymbol{G}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"47}
\DeclareMathSymbol{H}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"48}
\DeclareMathSymbol{I}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"49}
\DeclareMathSymbol{J}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"4A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{K}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"4B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{L}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"4C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{M}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"4D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{N}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"4E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{O}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"4F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{P}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"50}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Q}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"51}
\DeclareMathSymbol{R}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"52}
\DeclareMathSymbol{S}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"53}
\DeclareMathSymbol{T}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"54}
\DeclareMathSymbol{U}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"55}
\DeclareMathSymbol{V}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"56}
\DeclareMathSymbol{W}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"57}
\DeclareMathSymbol{X}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"58}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Y}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"59}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Z}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"5A}

\DeclareMathSymbol{a}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"61}
\DeclareMathSymbol{b}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"62}
\DeclareMathSymbol{c}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"63}
\DeclareMathSymbol{d}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"64}
\DeclareMathSymbol{e}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"65}
\DeclareMathSymbol{f}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"66}
\DeclareMathSymbol{g}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"67}
\DeclareMathSymbol{h}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"68}
\DeclareMathSymbol{i}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"69}
\DeclareMathSymbol{j}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"6A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{k}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"6B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{l}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"6C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{m}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"6D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{n}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"6E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{o}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"6F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{p}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"70}
\DeclareMathSymbol{q}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"71}
\DeclareMathSymbol{r}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"72}
\DeclareMathSymbol{s}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"73}
\DeclareMathSymbol{t}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"74}
\DeclareMathSymbol{u}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"75}
\DeclareMathSymbol{v}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"76}
\DeclareMathSymbol{w}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"77}
\DeclareMathSymbol{x}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"78}
\DeclareMathSymbol{y}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"79}
\DeclareMathSymbol{z}\mathalpha{pureletters}{"7A}
\begin{document}
$g$ in math mode

g in text mode
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[sfmath]{kpfonts}
\begin{document}
    $g$ in math mode

    g in text mode
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I prefer your  [typographic variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G).